# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: invalid name syntax Position: 16

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

#### Update

14 Aug - Passive position. We couldn't replicate the issue, the root cause or pattern is failed to be recognized. Hence we'll keep this under monitoring stage and revisit once it comes back again. Thanks for all who's commented for idea!

---

#### Original Question

This issue comes when we are trying to insert a new row of data into a particular table, however the issue is not persistent, we are unable to replicate. Any idea?

Error

```
2023-08-10 03:29:25.792  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42602
2023-08-10 03:29:25.793 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: invalid name syntax
  Position: 16
2023-08-10 03:29:25.794 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.z.e.service.maskedImpl  : could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Let me explain,

1. We deploy our code using Kubernetes, with 1 pod.
2. A fresh deployment will not see this issue, however after some time (still the same pod) .. the same code will break by throwing this error.
3. We notice a hacky solution to "resolve" this issue, which is deleting the pod and let it respawn. Immediately, it works fine again.

The entity is define as below in our code

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="\"maskedTableName\"")
public class maskedTableName {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="\"Id\"")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="\"maskedColumnA\"")
    private String maskedColumnA;

    @Column(name="\"maskedColumnB\"")
    private String maskedColumnB;
```

#### Additional info(s)

1. We tried running the same code within local host environment, we do not face issue like we described. So we safely assume all the logics work fine.
2. While this issue happen, we truncated the table and re-fire the API, hoping it it will create a new data row. It does not work as expected anyway.
3. Within the database itself, this `Id` column is the Primary key with default of `nextval('maskedSchema."maskedTable_Id_seq"'::regclass)`

Comment: might be a clue. go to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html find out match error name for 42602. that is "invalid_name". search source code for invalid_name.  error code is ERRCODE_INVALID_NAME. it's in function {regrolein,regnamespacein,stringToQualifiedNameList, textToQualifiedNameList) it means, some of your objects name does not ok.

Comment: Show us the problem SQL too.

Comment: hi @jarlh, my bad for making this clear in the question. We are using hibernate `.save` function, hence this is not a native query nor any SQL query to show.

Comment: Hi @jian, there's no lead to this honestly. Like I describe, when running it locally OR at fresh deployment, there's no such issue. Sometime later, it started this issue (without code changes / new deployment / changes in DB)

Comment: @TommyLeong, one suggestion would be turning on the hibernate SQL logger to write down the statements like jarlh has suggested in a previous comment. Even if you have not implemented a query, Hibernate has to do it to communicate with Postgres.
Also, when you tried running it locally, have you tried to build the docker image that runs on Kubernetes locally and start that docker image, or did you run it from your IDE? If you are on the second way, you are probably falling into an encoding mismatch into your docker image. Besides it is very curious that the behavior shows up after a while.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same scenario here and the solution was updating the parameter `spring.jpa.database-platform` from
`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
to
`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`